# Sqlite3 INSERT query ERROR?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

i want to insert in my DB 2 strings var

one entered from the user ==> H and

one generated form the chatbot==> B

Here is the code:

```
# initialize the connection to the database
sqlite_file = '/Users/emansaad/Desktop/chatbot1/brain.sqlite'
connection = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
connection.create_function("REGEXP", 2, regexp)
cursor = connection.cursor()
connection.text_factory = str
connection = open

def new_data(Input,Output):
     row = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM chatting_log WHERE user=?',(Input,)).fetchone()
     if row:
        return
     else:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO chatting_log VALUES (?, ?)', (Input, Output))

while True:
   print(("B:%s" % B))  
   H = input('H:')
   New_H= ' '.join(PreProcess_text(H))
   reply= cursor.execute('SELECT respoce FROM Conversation_Engine WHERE request REGEXP?',[New_H]).fetchone()
   if reply:
      B=reply[0]
      new_data(H,B)
```

The codes works perfectly in generating and selecting  the replay from the DB , but the problem is when i go back to the chatting_log table in the DB there is no data?

PS: i am using python 3

thank you,

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking what this regexp you're building actually looks like, and whether it actually matches anything?

Answer (score 2):

Always remember to commit the changes that you make. In this case: `connection.commit()`. Except it looks like you overrode your `connection` variable.

Comment: yes i've tried this solution but there is an error of:

Comment: sorry the error says: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: That is because you set `connection=open`. You are overwriting your connection instance. Don't overwrite that variable because you will need it to commit your data to the DB. May I ask why you have that line in your code?